# How to add "IF" to the batch script below?

Tags: batch-file

I have this line of code that checks for the IP address of a computer and runs a specific script if it matches.

Original script:

```
IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.50.">Nul 2>&1  && (Call sydprtcheck.bat) || (
IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.51.">Nul 2>&1  && Call sydprtcheck.bat)
```

I need to add this line of code:

```
if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%10.txt" call sydprtcheck.bat
```

What's the proper way of doing it?

```
IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.50.">Nul 2>&1  && ( if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%10.txt" call sydprtcheck.bat || (
IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.51.">Nul 2>&1  &&  if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%10.txt" call sydprtcheck.bat )
```

The script should do the following:

1- check for the IP address of a computer if the IP is within range then checks for a specific text file

2- if the text file not exist, then it calls for another script

3- if text file exists then exit the batch

4- if the IP address is not within range then goes to next line to check for a different IP address range

I've added the code to my batch script here is what it looks like:

```
for %%a in (50,51) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%10.txt" (
  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.%%a.">Nul 2>&1 && call printmap1.bat
) || ( 

goto Melprinters )
echo.

:Melprinters
for %%a in (1,5) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%11.txt" (
  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.%%a.">Nul 2>&1 && call printmap2.bat
) || ( 

goto Wynprinters )
echo.

:Wynprinters
for %%a in (60) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%12.txt" (
  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.%%a.">Nul 2>&1 && call printmap3.bat
) || ( 

goto Adlprinters )
echo.

:adlprinters

for %%a in (100) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%13.txt" (
  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.%%a.">Nul 2>&1 && call printmap4.bat
) || ( 

goto settime )
echo.

:settime
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There is one issue though. The part that checks for 50, 51 IP range works then the script ignores to check for IP range and only checks for text file existence.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"proper" is a matter of opinion.

The way I'd use is

```
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%10.txt" (set "runsub=") else (set "runsub=Y")
for %%a in (50,51) do if not defined runsub IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.%%a.">Nul 2>&1 && set "runsub=Y"

if defined runsub call sydprtcheck.bat
```

---

After description added - it is implied but not expressly stated that the file may be created by the subroutine,

```
for %%a in (50,51) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%10.txt" (
  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.%%a.">Nul 2>&1 && call sydprtcheck.bat
)
```

and for the additional question

```
for %%a in (100) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%10.txt" (
  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.%%a.">Nul 2>&1 && call sydprtcheck22.bat
)
```

Again, your addition isn't clear whether the same text file is used or not. The `for` control is probably redundant, but using it allows you to add `110` easily if required.

Comment: Great! It works, how do I add another line of code to call for different scripts. for example if IP address is "10.0.100.xxx" call for sydprtcheck22.bat ?

Comment: Thanks Magoo, yes the  text file is different for .100 IP range.